# Android data usage deeper dive

Tags: android, data-visualization

It used to be that the data usage summary allowed to select the time window and see what app has used what amount of data within that window.  This has changed several revisions ago and It has always bothered me.  Anyone know of a replacement that would do this?

Comment: I didn't check for quite a while, but maybe one of the battery helpers in [my app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batteryhelper) can do? I vaguely remember having seen [GSam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) praised. There was also some tool you could run on your PC to dive into the battery stats (via ADB IIRC) – I don't recall its name, was something like "Power Tutor". Then, [SuperUStats](https://f-droid.org/packages/superustats.tool.android/) could dive in per-app usage stats and might be worth a try.

Comment: @Izzy, GSam is a battery monitor, as are all of these you've mentioned. I'm looking for a data monitor.

Comment: By "data monitor", did you mean "mobile data usage", or basically, "internet data usage"?

Comment: Oh, my bad, apologies! The apps for data usage stats are [in this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics), right on top.

Comment: @AndrewT., mobile, but something that does both and can separate it would be great.